# In Meteor 1.3.x, how do you add a collection from within imports/api?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection of Appointments which I'm porting to the new 1.3 file structure. It is structured like the Todo app, but it is still not creating the Meteor collection.

**/imports/api/appointments/appointments.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { SimpleSchema } from 'meteor/aldeed:simple-schema';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Appointments = new Mongo.Collection('appointments');

Appointments.deny({
  insert() { return true; },
  update() { return true; },
  remove() { return true; },
});
```

**/imports/startup/server/index.js**

```
import './register-api.js';
```

**/imports/startup/server/register-api.js**

```
import '../../api/appointments/methods.js';
import '../../api/appointments/appointments.js';
import '../../api/orgs/orgs.js';
```

**Then, using "meteor mongo" and "show collections"**

```
availability
emailvariables
invitations
meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration
orgs
recurring
roles
services
system.indexes
users
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Mongo.Collection` doesn't create a MongoDB collection automatically. You'll need to perform an `insert` to have it created. Like so:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  Appointments.insert({foo: 1});
});
```

Comment: So I feel like an idiot. Was putting my fixtures.js off for a while